# How do I grab all parameters from a URL and print it out in PHP?

Tags: php

How do I print out all the parameters and their value from a URL without using e.g. `print $_GET['paramater-goes-here'];` multiple times?

Comment: You might want to read this to get to know the difference between `GET` and `POST`: http://insecureweb.com/web-security/http-methods-get-vs-post/

Answer (score 40):

I use

```
print_r($_GET);
```

Comment: such a lovely and simple answer. saved my time. #SF great use of opensource knowledge.

Answer (score 22):

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
  echo $key . " : " . $value . "<br />\r\n";
}
```

Comment: This answer's great, because while print_r is quicker, this allows you to use $key and $value in your code.

Answer (score 8):

The parameters are in the URL, so are available in `$_GET` ; and you can loop over that array using [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) :

```
foreach ($_GET as $name => $value) {
    echo $name . ' : ' . $value . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Its easy to get all request parameters from url.

```
<?php
  print_r($_REQUEST);
?>
```

This will return an array format.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `parse_url()` and `parse_str()`:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/index.php?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=some%20string';
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query);
parse_str($query, $arr);

echo $query;  // a=1&b=2&c=3&d=some%20string

echo $a;  // 1
echo $b;  // 2
echo $c;  // 3
echo $d;  // some string

foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    echo $key . ' => ' . $val . ', ';  // a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4
}
```

Comment: Actually this a nice answer because you can parse a string url outside of a request

Answer (score 1):

Try this.....

```
function get_all_get()
{
    $output = "?"; 
    $firstRun = true; 

    foreach($_GET as $key=>$val) { 
        if(!$firstRun) { 
            $output .= "&"; 
        } else { 
            $firstRun = false; 
        } 
        $output .= $key."=".$val;
    } 

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this, this little function you wrote saved me some time, albeit I had to rework it for more of a functional use, but nonetheless what I needed. Didn't think about going this route.

Comment: what is '$parameter' ?  Undefined $parameter

Comment: That's better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i use:

```
   ob_start();
   var_dump($_GET);
   $s=ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score -1):

i use:

```
       $get = $_REQUEST;
        $query_string = '?';
        foreach ($get as $key => $value) {
            $query_string .=  $key . '=' . $value . '&';
        }

        $query_string;
```

Comment: The question is about the parameters in the URL. The gets the data from the URL **and** the request body **and** the cookies. It's also vulnerable to XSS attacks.